# determine duplication rate per group

Tags: sql, hive

EDIT: Previous sample data included the duplicate visits column I need that calculated in the solution.

I am trying to determine the

`total_visits = total visits per website per sub_group`

`duplicate_visits = visits-1`

`duplication_rate = duplicate_visits/ total_visits`

`distinct_users_subgroup = distinct users per website per sub_group`

`distinct_users_total = distinct users per website`

for the sample data below which I hope to be a suitable reprex. The table is grouped at the `website` and `sub_group` levels and gives the number of `visits` for each user. How can a query be written to get the results below?

Data:

```
+---------+---------+-----------+--------+
| website | user_id | sub_group | visits |
+---------+---------+-----------+--------+
| web1    |       1 | A         |      1 |
| web1    |       1 | B         |      3 |
| web1    |       1 | C         |      4 |
| web1    |       1 | D         |      1 |
| web1    |       2 | A         |      3 |
| web1    |       2 | B         |      4 |
| web1    |       3 | B         |      2 |
| web1    |       3 | C         |      1 |
| web1    |       3 | D         |      1 |
| web2    |       1 | A         |      3 |
| web2    |       1 | B         |      1 |
| web2    |       1 | C         |      2 |
| web2    |       4 | B         |      1 |
| web2    |       4 | D         |      2 |
| web2    |       5 | C         |      3 |
| web2    |       5 | D         |      4 |
+---------+---------+-----------+--------+
```

Results:

```
+---------+-----------+--------------+------------------+----------------+-------------------------+----------------------+
| website | sub_group | total_visits | duplicate_visits | duplicate_rate | distinct_users_subgroup | distinct_users_total |
+---------+-----------+--------------+------------------+----------------+-------------------------+----------------------+
| web1    | A         |            4 |                2 |           0.50 |                       2 |                    3 |
| web1    | B         |            9 |                6 |           0.67 |                       3 |                    3 |
| web1    | C         |            5 |                3 |           0.60 |                       2 |                    3 |
| web1    | D         |            2 |                0 |           0.00 |                       2 |                    3 |
| web2    | A         |            3 |                2 |           0.67 |                       1 |                    3 |
| web2    | B         |            2 |                0 |           0.00 |                       2 |                    3 |
| web2    | C         |            5 |                3 |           0.60 |                       2 |                    3 |
| web2    | D         |            6 |                4 |           0.67 |                       2 |                    3 |
+---------+-----------+--------------+------------------+----------------+-------------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: I technically need a HiveQL solution but as long as the SQL solution uses methods available in HQL it is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  size(collect_set(user_id)) to count distinct users and the same can be calculated as analytic function to count distinct users for website.

```
SELECT website, 
       sub_group, 
       Sum(visits)                AS total_visits, 
       sum(visits-1)              AS duplicate_visits, 
       sum(visits-1)/Sum(visits)  AS duplicate_rate,
       size(collect_set(user_id)) AS distinct_users_subgroup,
       size(collect_set(user_id)) over (partition by website) AS distinct_users_total 
FROM table
GROUP BY website, sub_group;
```

Or if your Hive version does not support aggregation and analytics functions together in the same subquery, calculate distinct_users_total in the subquery:

```
SELECT website, 
       sub_group, 
       Sum(visits)                AS total_visits, 
       sum(visits-1)              AS duplicate_visits, 
       sum(visits-1)/Sum(visits)  AS duplicate_rate,
       size(collect_set(user_id)) AS distinct_users_subgroup,
       distinct_users_total 
FROM (select t.*,
             size(collect_set(user_id)) over (partition by website) AS distinct_users_total
        from table t) s
GROUP BY website, sub_group, distinct_users_total;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi statq the resume to one table can be a bit confusing so I am gona do it in parts - at the moment I have only a access db to run the query so I will keep the sql extremly simple (depending on your sistem you can use other SQL verbs that make the code more compact):

=> the table is called "teste"

first SQL to get all but the last two columns:

```
SELECT website, 
       sub_group, 
       Sum(visits) AS total_visits, 
       Count(*) AS duplicate_visits, 
       1-Count(*)/Sum(visits) AS duplicate_rate
FROM teste
GROUP BY website, sub_group
```

second sql to get the data for the penultimate colum

```
SELECT website, 
       sub_group, 
       count(user_id) AS distinct_users_subgroup
FROM (SELECT website, 
             sub_group, 
             user_id 
      FROM teste
      GROUP BY website, sub_group, user_id)
GROUP BY website, sub_group
```

third sql for the last column:

```
SELECT website, 
       Count(user_id) AS distinct_users_total 
FROM (SELECT website, 
             user_id 
      FROM teste
      GROUP BY website, user_id )  
GROUP BY website
```

It is possible to join these 3 results to one result frame though it looks very messy within the simplied SQL DB I have at hand (and I could not test this part so there might be a typo)

```
SELECT a.*,
       b.distinct_users_subgroup, 
       c.distinct_users_total 
FROM (SELECT website, 
             sub_group, 
             Sum(visits) AS total_visits, 
             Count(*) AS duplicate_visits, 
             1-Count(*)/Sum(visits) AS duplicate_rate
      FROM teste
      GROUP BY website, sub_group) as a
INNER JOIN (SELECT website, 
                   sub_group, 
                   count(user_id) AS distinct_users_subgroup
             FROM (SELECT website, 
                          sub_group, 
                          user_id 
                   FROM teste
                   GROUP BY website, sub_group, user_id)
             GROUP BY website, sub_group) as b on a.website = b.website and a.sub_group = b.sub_group
INNER JOIN (SELECT website, 
                   Count(user_id) AS distinct_users_total 
            FROM (SELECT website, 
                         user_id 
                  FROM teste
                  GROUP BY website, user_id )  
                        GROUP BY website) as c on a.website = c.website
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to make the change  `sum(visits-1)  AS duplicate_visits` and `sum(visits-1) /Sum(visits) AS duplicate_rate` in the first sub-query to get my desired results. Curious if  that change is doing what I think it is in general.

Comment: Also why is it that I don't need either a distinct in the count  or a distinct in the select for the sub-queries in the inner joins?

Comment: hi statq - the DB System I have available does not suport DISTINCT within groupings so I had to nest a "grouping" to get only unique combinations and then count them before joining them (it is efectively a "distinct" but without using this verb it self). Depending on your DB you should be able to use a "distinct" - I just prefered to use a solution I could test to make sure it runs.